# How do append a <text> for every element of the data in a D3 svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

[Sorry the title was quite badly formulated. I would change it if I could.]

I'm searching for a way to append text elements from a array or arrays in the data.

EDIT: I can already do a 1 level enter `.data(mydata).enter()`. What I'm trying here is a second level of enter. Like if `mydata` was an object which contained an array `mydata.sourceLinks`.

*cf.* the coments in this small code snippet:

```
var c = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll(".node")
    .data(d.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(i) {
        return "translate(" + i.x + "," + i.y + ")"
    })
c.append("text")
    .attr("x", -200)
    .attr("y", 30)
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("font-size","10px")
    .text(function(d){

        // d.sourceLinks is an array of elements
        // console.log(d.sourceLinks[0].target.name);
        // Here I would like to apped('text') for each of the elements in the array
        // and write d.sourceLinks[i].target.name in this <text>

    })
    ;
```

---

I tried a lot of different things with .data(d).enter() but it never worked and I got lot's of errors.

I also tried to insert html instead of text where I could insert linebreaks (that's ultimately what I'm trying to achieve).

I also tried

```
c.append("foreignobject")
    .filter(function(i) { // left nodes
        return i.x < width / 2;
    })
    .attr('class','sublabel')
    .attr("x", -200)
    .attr("y", 30)
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200)
    .append("body")
    .attr("xmlns","http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
    .append("div");
```

but this never showed up anywhere in my page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question was not exactly clear, until I see [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573175/how-do-append-a-text-for-every-element-of-the-data-in-a-d3-svg/41573509#comment70381488_41573509). So, if you want to deal with data that is an array of arrays, you can have several "enter" selections in nested elements, since the child inherits the data from the parent.

Suppose that we have this array of arrays:

```
var data = [
    ["colours", "green", "blue"],
    ["shapes", "square", "triangle"],
    ["languages", "javascript", "c++"]
];
```

We will bind the data to groups, as you did. Then, for each group, we will bind the individual array to the text elements. That's the important thing in the data function:

```
.data(d => d)
```

That makes the child selection receiving an individual array of the parent selection.

Check the snippet:

```js
var data = [
    ["colours", "green", "blue"],
    ["shapes", "square", "triangle"],
    ["languages", "javascript", "c++"]
];

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 200);

var groups = svg.selectAll("groups")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", (d, i) => "translate(" + (50 + i * 100) + ",0)");

var texts = groups.selectAll("texts")
    .data(d => d)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("y", (d, i) => 10 + i * 20)
    .text(d => d);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Now, regarding your code. if `d.nodes` is an array of arrays, these are the changes:

```
var c = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll(".node")
    .data(d.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(i) {
        return "translate(" + i.x + "," + i.y + ")"
    });//this selection remains the same

var myTexts = c.selectAll("myText")//a new selection using 'c'
    .data(function(d){ return d;})//we bind each inner array
    .enter()//we have a nested enter selection
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", -200)
    .attr("y", 30)
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("font-size", "10px")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d;//change here according to your needs
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `enter` like this :

```
var data = ["aaa", "abc", "abd"];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", 200)
  .attr("height", 200);

svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d,i) {
        return 20 + 50 * i;
    })        
    .attr("y", 100) 
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

See this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/t3eyqu7z/

Comment: This is a basic 1st level enter which I already use. What I'm asking is a second level of enter. Like if data was an array of arrays

Comment: Oh ok, let me have a look

Comment: @stallingone I would do smthing like that I guess https://jsfiddle.net/t3eyqu7z/1/